# build order of post build actions in hudson

Tags: hudson, integration-testing, war

I want to run an integration test an to an WAR (in tomcat) using hudson as continous build server.

The post build action to start a script is higher on the list than the deploy action, so I assume it is executed BEFORE the deploying is done.
So how do I deploy and THEN start a script to run my test?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, is to write a script to deploy WAR on desired Tomcat server (it should not be complicated) instead of using deploy plugin and then run the script with test.